# Multiple assignment between lists in Mathematica 7

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose there are two lists `a = {a1, a2, a3}` and `b = {b1, b2, b3}`, and I want to write an assignment statement to make `a1=b1,a2=b2,a3=b3` which only refers to `a` and `b`:

```
Thread[a = b]
```

But it only makes `a={b1,b2,b3}`. Using `:=` (SetDelayed) instead of `=` doesn't work either.
Any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `Thread` only works on "explicit" lists; the variables need to be expanded before being operated on.

After some experimentation, this works for me:

```
a = {a1, a2, a3};
b = {b1, b2, b3};
Thread[Set[Evaluate@a, Evaluate@b]];
{a1, a2, a3}
```

You could also write `Thread[Evaluate@a = Evaluate@b]`; just depends whichever you find more readable.

Comment: Thanks.Actually Evaluate@a = Evaluate@b is enough.I didn't know the command 'Evaluate'.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

MapThread[Set,{{a1,a2,a3},{b1,b2,b3}}]

?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
a = {a1, a2, a3};
b = {b1, b2, b3};

each[{x_, y_}, Transpose[{a, b}],
  x = y]
```

Which uses my handy `each` function:

```
SetAttributes[each, HoldAll];                (* each[pattern, list, body]     *)
each[pat_, lst_, bod_] :=                    (*  converts pattern to body for *)
  Scan[Replace[#, pat:>bod]&, Evaluate@lst]  (*   each element of list.       *)
```

Similarly, you can do this:

```
MapThread[(#1 = #2)&, {a, b}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if they are really called `a1`, `a2`, etc, you could do this:

```
Assign[x_, y_] := Module[{s1, s2, n, sn},
  s1 = SymbolName[Unevaluated[x]];
  s2 = SymbolName[Unevaluated[y]];

    For[n = 1, n <= Length[x] && n <= Length[y], n++,
      sn = ToString[n];
      Evaluate[Symbol[s1 <> sn]] = Evaluate[Symbol[s2 <> sn]]
    ]
  ]

SetAttributes[Assign, HoldAll]
```

And then

```
Clear[b1, b2, b3];
Clear[a1, a2, a3];

a = {a1, a2, a3}
b = {b1, b2, b3}

Assign[a, b]
a
```

Gives the results for `a`, `b` and `a` again as:

```
{a1, a2, a3}
{b1, b2, b3}
{b1, b2, b3}
```

As expected.

In general you can create expressions like these from proper use of `SymbolName` and `Symbol`, but be careful with your evaluation. If I had written `SymbolName[x]` (without the `Unevaluated`) then it would've interpreted that as `SymbolName[{a1, a2, a3}]`, which is clearly not desirable. Not using `Evaluate` on `Symbol[s1 <> sn]` will have Mathematica complain that you're trying to reassign the `Symbol` function.

Comment: Yikes. I think I prefer my solution `:)`

Comment: Yes, yours is infinitely better. (Upvoted) I blame the early morning, and months of working in imperative languages without touching Mathematica :)

Comment: Oh, I definitely know that feeling!